# Automatically re-populate the cache at expiry time

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I currently cache the result of a method invocation.

The caching code follows the standard pattern: it uses the item in the cache if it exists, otherwise it calculates the result, caching it for future calls before returning it.

I would like to shield client code from cache misses (e.g. when the item has expired).

I am thinking of spawning a thread to wait for the lifetime of the cached object, to then run a supplied function to repopulate the cache when (or just before) the existing item expires.

Can anyone share any experience related to this? Does this sound like a sensible approach?

I'm using .NET 4.0.

Comment: I will be using the caching in asp.net. I left the question relatively technology agnostic as I felt the approach was relatively independent of the technology.

Comment: I am looking into this and considering a System.Timers.Timer instead of spawning a new thread and yes refresh just before expiry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is ASP.NET, the [`Cache.Insert()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05kd8d77.aspx) method allows you to specify a callback delegate.

> Does this sound like a sensible approach?

Yes, the callback (and File-dependency) are supplied for exactly this kind of situation. You still have ro make a trade of between resources, latency and out-of-dateness.

Comment: This answers my original question as I envisaged. I am unsure of the usefulness of the distinction Steven Sudit makes between caching and snapshotting (I haven't come across the distinction before). I'd be interested to learn more.

Comment: on the call back you loos the current http context is there an elegant way around that?

Answer (score 4):

A new addition to the .NET Framework 4.0 is the [MemoryCache Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx)

Quote from the Docs:

> The MemoryCache class is similar to
> the ASP.NET Cache class. The
> MemoryCache class has many properties
> and methods for accessing the cache
> that will be familiar to you if you
> have used the ASP.NET Cache class

You could use the AddOrGetExisting Method to get or create a CacheItem if does not exist.

Comment: Nice link, didn't know about that. But AddOrGetExisting would still count as a cache-miss, Ben should use a callback. That seems supported.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a cache that never expires anything:

```
var cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>();

var value = cache.GetOrAdd(someKey, key => MyMethod(key));
```

Does that help?

---

Here's a cache that never expires anything and refreshes the value after a certain lifetime:

```
var cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Tuple<TValue, DateTime>>();

var value = cache.AddOrUpdate(someKey,
             key => Tuple.Create(MyMethod(key), DateTime.Now),
    (key, value) => (value.Item2 + lifetime < DateTime.Now)
                  ? Tuple.Create(MyMethod(key), DateTime.Now)
                  : value)
                  .Item1;
```

Does that help?

Comment: But it never refreshes anything either

Comment: OK, nice addition. But the ASP cache also has a priority mechanism abs timeout, sliding timeout, defaults,  ...  (still +1 :)

Comment: I would generally prefer to let a value expire when it's old, then postpone getting a new value until and unless it's actually desired.

Comment: @Steven: that makes way too much assumptions about the OP's situation.

Comment: @Henk: Perhaps, but what you're describing isn't caching, it's snapshotting. For example, if I have a table of rarely-changing data, such as the list of states in the USA, I don't want to hit the database each time, but I also don't want to cache the list forever because, hey, things change. So I generate a snapshot that expires after some reasonable but arbitrary period of time (an hour, a day) and then replace it with a new snapshot. That's not caching. Caching would be keeping values that expire only to make room for more useful ones, with misses resolved on an as-needed basis.

Comment: @Steven, we're descending into semantics. A cache with auto reload looks a lot like a Snapshot but I could still point out differences. A more practical point: ASP.NET does have a Cache object but not a Snapshot object. But let's cut this comment-trail, you could ask this as a Question.

Comment: @Henk: I'm not interesting is semantics, but rather in pointing out a genuine distinction. By definition, a cache is something that can be sized down to zero but still work for read-through and write-through. You're talking about a different animal entirely, which uses cache-like algorithms but towards a different end. As for a question, I'm not sure what I'd ask.

Answer (score -1):

There doesn't seem to be any point in expiring an object just to immediately recreate it. Just turn off expiration; dtb shows how.

Comment: And the refresh? That's another function of a cache.

Comment: How is the old object any worse than the new one? If it's not, then let's leave it alone. On the other hand, if the OP had a simple wrapper that amounted to "get it from the cache if possible, else create it and incidentally add it to the cache", this would be fine.

Comment: If it is a static calculation you would be right. But consider a query or webservice. Caching is usually a trade-of between performance and freshness. And the OP addressed the other part: preventing cache-misses

Comment: You can't prevent cache misses. That's why it's called a cache.

Comment: @Henk: Sorry, forgot the prefix again.

Comment: Steven, if you reload after expiration (and maybe even preload on startup) you _can_ prevent cache misses. No problem.

Comment: @Henk: If a cache miss is impossible, it's not a cache.

Comment: This doesn't address the original question of getting a fresh value.